# Bank is not depositing my new account promotion bonus

Tags: banking, bank-account, savings-account, checking-account, financial-advisor

I opened a bank account in response to a promotion in a big bank. Originally it was saying `if I keep my money (50K) for 60 days, I get $600`. The agent at the branch didn't say anything more. Then they said I get my bonus after a month after requirement was met. And now still nothing happened. I called customer service and they say different things. One says `they just processed my eligibility this morning`! And next person says `you will get your bonus after 90 days`. Even if I take my money and keep the bank open, they say it is not free and I will be charged monthly.

I planned accordingly and bought a house. We all plan based on the information we are given. A lot lies, wrong information, and deceiving in this case. I request for my own application and promotion package, and they say `we can not provide you that`.

I'm getting tired of all these. What should I do? Any advices?

**UPDATE2:**

The branch after my customer calls and my complaints, keep sending me emails asking to send my GREEN CARD. I'm not sure why that is needed. They say it is needed for investigation and bonus payment, which looks deceptive to me (especially that they copied it when I was opening my account). Any reasons why they might need it?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because either this belongs on law.stackexchange or is specific to the bank in question.

Comment: Its financial question. Why off topic?

Comment: If it is a law suit question then ask law.stackexchange.  If it is a how to deal with XYZ bank that is also beyond the scope of this site.  Either way this question has nothing to do with personal finance.

Comment: I deleted the last sentence. I'm generally asking for money management advice in these situations.

Comment: Bank + account + promotion bonus + monthly fees sounds like finance to me.  And even if it's borderline because the focus is on poor customer service, I think that closing such questions discourages participation.  That's my 2 cents (also financial).

Comment: This question is indeed on topic, in my opinion. It falls under the category of “Consumer issues or consumer protections” from our [on-topic help page](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We [do not disqualify questions because someone is having an issue with a particular business](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2159/10997).

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this will help but, It's my understanding that there are usually two deadlines, one in the marketing materials and one in the fine print.

The marketing materials will say something like 'deposit $X and we'll give you $Y after the account is 90 days old."  The fine print will then say something along the lines of 'we'll rescind the bonus if you close the account within 6 months.'  Usually, particularly with savings account offers, this means leaving a substantial amount of money in an account that earns a terribly below market interest rate for an additional three months or pay an account maintenance fee that eats part of the welcome bonus.  The offers are structured this way on purpose.  The bank doesn't want to just hand every passer-by $600.  The bank wants new accounts.

Separately, these offers are/can be regional.  If you call a national toll-free number for customer service, those folks probably don't have fully adequate information at their disposal.  The branch where you opened the account might have the applicable information, but they're probably under no obligation to give you the marketing materials.  I'd try at the branch and be exceedingly nice to the person/people you talk to.

Comment: I am not sure how you eked out a good answer from the question, but somehow you did.  +1